# Simple calculation based on fields

Tags: sql

So first I need to create a variable made of curr_bal - PTP and name the result curr_bal_pcd

Then i need to sum Curr_bal-curr_bal_pcd/Curr_bal. however the values need to be divided by 100 as there is no decimals in the fields

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, just write the formula as the column value, and alias the column with the name

```
SELECT ...
   (curr_bal - PTP) curr_bal_pcd,
   ...
```

For the 2nd one,

```
   curr_bal - curr_bal_pcd
=> curr_bal - (curr_bal - PTP)
=> PTP
```

So you're really looking to sum

```
   PTP/Curr_bal
```

Not sure about your comment re: `divided by 100`. If you mean the base columns `curr_bal` and `PTP` are implicitly in cents, then the ratio being summed doesn't care (dividing both by 100 achieves 0 net effect), whereas you can tack `/100.0` to the first expression.

Comment: To get a percentage, you'd need `PTP/(Curr_bal/100.0)`, wouldn't you?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, percentage would multiply a rate by 100. Re-reading, I'm not even sure that's what the author was after

Comment: Dividing both values by 100 is a no-op, but the simple reading of the question suggests that's what's wanted.  I think there's a small measure of confusion in the question.  You got my upvote for the (simple) rearrangement of the arithmetic.